# Firebase anonymous auth lost after failed reauth

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase 3.4.1 on an iOS React Native app. I use anonymous auth to ensure that users can only read/write their own data (i.e. security rules check `auth && auth.uid`).

On first run, I call `firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()`, and on subsequent app opens, I set up the listener

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    // success
  } else {
    // something is wrong
  }
}, (err) => {
  // log error
});
```

I have noticed that a few users hit the `something is wrong` branch above, where the `user` object returned on auth change is null. I suspected this may be some intermittent failure to reauth against Firebase, but it seemed like once someone experienced this error, it was permanent.

In an effort to replicate, with my own user account that had been granted anonymous auth, I disabled the auth credential from the Firebase dashboard, which would prevent me from reauthing. When I then try to reauth, I too hit the `something is wrong` branch above, as expected (surprisingly, the error function is not called). However, after I flip my credential back to enabled on the dashboard, I can no longer successfully reauth and continue to receive a null `user` object on auth change.

Is there any way to reauth once it's failed once?

Comment: If you sign in anonymously, the session should be indefinite. At you sure you are not signing out the anonymous user somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yeah, there is no sign out call in my code. It's as if the SDK invalidates the locally-stored credential after a single failure, which would be unexpected.

Comment: If you disabled a user, it is possible the user would be forcefully signed out. Is that the case for you? Are you disabling the anonymous user?

Comment: @bojeil for the purpose of my test above, I did disable the user. I'm surprised that an attempt to authenticate against a disabled credential would "sign out" the user -- technically the user is not authed at this point, so "forcefully signed out" seems to suggest that the locally-stored auth details are deleted. This clearly is problematic in the anonymous auth situation, where it would be impossible for the client to reclaim that credential. In effect, disabling an anonymous user's credential is equivalent to deleting it.

Comment: For my app, I have *not* disabled any credentials, so it appears there is a separate bug, where anonymous users periodically are unable to authenticate, triggering this "force sign out" code.

Comment: A disabled user being signed out is the expected behavior. However, from what you observe, the user is being signed out when he is not disabled. Not sure why this is happening. In react native, asyncStorage is used underneath. Do you only notice this in anonymous users? How about when you sign in with an email and password. It will help isolate the root cause of this problem.

Comment: We only use anonymous auth in our app, and I haven't been able to reproduce loss of auth credentials without disabling. <2% of our users experience this. I'll just go ahead and shift any dependencies on auth in the app to something else. Thank you for looking into this nonetheless.

Comment: Hey wsun, the latest Firebase version fixed a react native persistence bug. Please upgrade to the latest version and try again.